# Ant script for jar creation - exclude from all filesets

Tags: java, ant

I'm building a jar file in eclipse using an ant script, and I want to exclude all files matching a certain pattern (for example, anything in the com directory).
I can exclude for a specific fileset by using -

```
            <fileset dir="./SomeProject/bin/classes">
                <exclude name="**/com/**" />
            </fileset>
```

And this works fine. The problem is, I have **a lot** of different filesets (including some zipfilesets), and any one of them can potentially have files I want to exclude. Is there any way to create an exclude command for the entire jar file?

I tried adding it to the target, e.g.

```
<jar destfile="${dir.jarfile}/exampleJar.jar" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain" excludes="**/com/**">
```

but that doesn't seem to do anything. I've also tried adding the `<exclude>` tag outside of a fileset, but that also doesn't do anything either.

How do I do create a global exclude for the entire project? Is that even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps a [multirootfileset](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/multirootfileset.html)?

Comment: That could work for the regular filesets, replacing them with basedirs, but can that also be used for zipfilesets? I have some external jars I'm using and want to exclude unnecessary files from those as well

Comment: What about [presetdef](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/presetdef.html), or perhaps just creating a single patternset with an `id` and then using `patternset refid` throughout your build file?

Comment: That helps. I used a zipgroupfileset to combine all jars to a single jar, then I use multirootfileset for my source code and zipfileset for the combined jar, all with the same patternset. Works great, thanks!